# Convert mp3 to aac with HE-AAC (AAC+) - linux

Tags: compression, mp3, aac

I'm currently working on lose size of mp3 files to streaming it.
I want to reduce size of mp3 how much how it is possible. I know best (probably) encode is HE-AAC (AAC+). He gave me 32kb/s for stereo sound of mp3 like 320kb/s from original.

I'm on Ubuntu. 
I found one solution. 
It's a NeroAacEnc it's free and working not bad too. 
But have a bug. Input file must be a "wav" file, so when I convert first my mp3 (400mb) to wav a get more than 4GB file.
Then I can not open so large files in NeroAacEnc.

Command with -ignorelength not work

```
$ neroAacEnc -ignorelength -br 32000 -if test.wav -of test_nero.mp3
```

Can you help me, and find solution how to do it right?
Other encoders are so bad to reduce size down to 32kb/s because so lose quality. Only HE-AAC (AAC+) give me good quality and 32kb/s of my file.

**EDIT:**
OK I found that I can compile ffmpeg with AAC+ encoder.
http://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/libaacplus_8c-source.html
here is a source. But I don't know how to do it, anyone know?

Answer (score 0):

> He gave me 32kb/s for stereo sound of mp3 like 320kb/s from original.

That's a total lie.  Whomever told you that has absolutely no idea what they're talking about.

> so when I convert first my mp3 (400mb) to wav a get more than 4GB file

Yes, that's likely.  Don't convert it to a file, pipe to it.  neuroAacEnc supports `-if -` to read from STDIN.

> Other encoders are so bad to reduce size down to 32kb/s because so lose quality.

All codecs sound bad at 32k.

> Only HE-AAC (AAC+) give me good quality and 32kb/s of my file.

HE-AAC is one of your best choices, but it still isn't going to be amazing.  Also consider Opus.

You might consider a pre-built FFmpeg for your usage.  Really though, you shouldn't be converting from MP3 to AAC anyway.  Go get the original audio if at all possible, or you're going to be wasting a lot of bandwidth trying to encode artifacts from previous lossy codecs.

Answer (score 0):

OK guys, after research I finaly done what I gonna do.
However We cannot split and marge files. When you try merge files encoded in AAC+ you lose it because tools to merge files encode again files in bad codec.

But we can compress big (>4gb) wav file to aac in live by command

```
rm audio.fifo; mkfifo audio.fifo; cat test.wav > audio.fifo & neroAacEnc -ignorelength -br 23000 -if audio.fifo -of test.m4a
```

This use temporary fifo file.

Obus (ogg) are not bad too but here https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/HighQualityAudio#Recommendedminimumbitratestouse
they show us that best quality is with he-aac with lowest bitrate.

PS. I know convert from mp3, to wav to aac is not really good method but my sources files are mp3's.

PS2. I know that 32kb/s in AAC+ is not sound like mp3 320kb/s but casual user who listening music from preview in streaming he will not listen to the details and will be happy.

Answer (score -1):

In case you don't find a better solution consider that .waw and .aac files are easy to split and merge.